# String error when expanding a dynamic array

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having a problem with trying to append an extra element to a dynamic array. I know I can use vectors, but for academic purposes, I have to use arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyList
{
protected:
    T* elems;
    int itsSize;
public:
    MyList(int itsSize):itsSize(itsSize)
    {
        elems = new T[itsSize];
    }

    ~MyList()
    {
        delete [] elems;
    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return itsSize;
    }

    virtual void addElem(){}
    virtual void getElem(){}
};

template <class T>
class MyStack : public MyList<T>
{
    int counter;
public:
    MyStack(int size):MyList<T>::MyList(size){counter=0;}

    void addElem()
    {
        T* tmp = new T[counter+1];

        for (int i = 0; i<counter+1; i++)
            tmp[i] = MyList<T>::elems[i];
        counter++;

        delete [] MyList<T>::elems;
        MyList<T>::elems = tmp;

        cin >> MyList<T>::elems[counter-1];
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            string line;
            getline(cin, line);
            throw "Wrong String Input--> will enter 0";
        }

    }

    void getElem()
    {
        for(int i=counter-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            cout << "Element-->" << MyList<T>::elems[i] << endl;
        }
    }

};


int main()
{
        int storeChoice;
        cout << "Would you like to store integers, strings or rectangles (1,2, or 3)?" << endl;
        cin >> storeChoice;

        if(storeChoice==1)
        {
            MyStack<int> numList(1);

            cout << "Enter num:";
            numList.addElem();

            bool choiceAddLoop = true;
            while(choiceAddLoop == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    char choiceAdd;
                    cout << "Would you like to enter another elem?(y/n)" << endl;
                    cin >> choiceAdd;
                    if(choiceAdd=='y')
                    {
                        try
                        {
                         cout << "Enter num:";
                         numList.addElem();
                        }
                        catch(const char* wrongInput)
                        {
                         cout << wrongInput << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(choiceAdd=='n')
                    {
                        choiceAddLoop=false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        throw "Invalid Input.";

                }
                catch(const char* invalidChoice)
                {
                    cout << invalidChoice;
                }
            }

                 cout << endl << "All Elements" << endl;
                 numList.getElem();
        }
        else if(storeChoice==2)
        {
            MyStack<string> stringList(1);

            cout << "Enter string:";
            stringList.addElem();

            bool choiceAddLoop = true;
            while(choiceAddLoop == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    char choiceAdd;
                    cout << "Would you like to enter another elem?(y/n)" << endl;
                    cin >> choiceAdd;
                    if(choiceAdd=='y')
                    {
                         cout << "Enter string:";
                         stringList.addElem();
                    }
                    else if(choiceAdd=='n')
                    {
                        choiceAddLoop=false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        throw "Invalid Input.";

                }
                catch(const char* invalidChoice)
                {
                    cout << invalidChoice;
                }
            }

              cout << endl << "All Elements" << endl;
              stringList.getElem();
        }
        }
```

When I select the first choice ( integer ) the code will work:

```
Would you like to store integers, strings or rectangles (1,2, or 3)?
1
Enter num:22
Would you like to enter another elem?(y/n)
y
Enter num:3
Would you like to enter another elem?(y/n)
n

All Elements
Element-->3
Element-->22

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.162 s
Press any key to continue.
```

A problem occurs in the second choice (string):

```
Would you like to store integers, strings or rectangles (1,2, or 3)?
2
Enter string:hello
Would you like to enter another elem?(y/n)
y
Enter string:terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 6.761 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It's the same code for both, why does it work only with integers?

Comment: not sure if thats the problem, but in any case you need to read about the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: You read out of bounds in `addElem`.

Comment: Prefixing inherited members with the base class makes code pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when you call `MyStack<T>::addElem()`. When you copy the elements from the old array to the new array your loop should stop at `counter`, not `counter+1`. Correct version:

```
for (int i = 0; i<counter; i++)
    tmp[i] = MyList<T>::elems[i];
```

Accessing `MyList<T>::elems[counter]`, which is out of bounds, results in undefined behavior. For the `int`-case you were just lucky that the data currently stored there could be correctly interpreted as integer, with `std::string` you had less luck. So the random data which you wanted to interpret as `std::string` caused the error you got.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6zvMzq)